# Is it okay to link to academic papers I uploaded on my cloud?

Tags: discussion

Many times, people quotes studies that are either hidden behind a paywall or some extremely greedy materialistic site like *John Wiley & Sons*.

Or even worse, many times I quote a study and I feel a bit obligated to provide a link for it as an answer.

One member told me once:

> That link isn't to the study. This makes it hard to check whether the study took reasonable care to avoid confounders

When I replied saying that it is not my job to provide links to studies he said:

> Ah, but on this site we want to see the references to the authoritative study, preferably as a link so we can check it quickly.

With my robust search skills, and having an free full online access to the largest library in town (academic papers, journals, studies, books), I can easily find full access to studies, so I started exporting a PDF file and uploading it to my Google Drive.

While I might not be allowed to do it, sometimes it is necessary and help other members see the content.

So I started uploading full studies to my google drive and linking them.

I don't really care if it might upset the publisher, the publishers usually are businesses (like Wiley) or universities (like Stanford) with billion dollars in assets and net worth. If they think their rights are violated they'll have to go to the process of sending a DMCA request to Google, then Google would take appropriate action.

Also, the moderator's job is not to verify if links violate a copyright law.

My only concern, is that I don't want this to cause problems on skepitcs.se.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not work for a couple of reasons.

1. Copyright violation. It *is* the job of moderators (community, elected or employees) to remove obvious infringement. Also, we must routinely remove material to comply to DMCA requests.
2. Dependency on your good will. Your answers are owned by the community. If you ever decide to leave the site, you'd take the sources with you, or force us to edit them all.

What you can do is this:

- link to a stable source of the study, e.g. PubMed. Many of us can read the papers from there.
- read the study to assess its viability, obviously
- provide a relevant verbatim quote from the study. This is well within the boundaries of copyright law *also because you give a valid source*.

While we might not notice that copyrighted material is linked to on the site, we will remove it if we do.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will delete this question because it has a -1 and I don't like it when my questions are downvoted.